# Is there any other way in PHP to access the database, aside from SQL queries?

Tags: php, sql, linq, data-access

I'm new to PHP and passing SQL queries by string in the backend doesn't seem really safe and DRY. I was thinking perhaps there is another way. Maybe something similar to Entity Framework and LINQ in .NET.

I know that there is PHPLinq but that project is dead for a while now.

**Update 1:** [The Doctrine project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) does seem to add some improvement to the data access in PHP, but it still relies heavily on SQL, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

**Update 2:** So I've dug up another project ([YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo)) that implements LINQ-like syntax on PHP. Perhaps I'll give'it a try, but it seems that it has nothing to do with database access.

Comment: Of course you can use NoSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the ORM for PHP. For example [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: I've looked at doctrine, and it does improve the things a little. But I would like to avoid writing SQL in the backend whatsoever.
PLinq looks promising, but the latest commits were made two years ago (2012).

Comment: So try any other ORM, there's a lot of solutions in Google :)